# tsocks not tunneling to ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, socks, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

My network is set up like this

S1 -> Switch <- S2 -> Internet

S2 is running an SSH service that I want to tunnel all traffic through.

I installed `tsocks` on S1 and set up the `tsocks.config` file like this:

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 1234
server_type = 5
```

then on S1 I ran this command:

```
ssh -D 1234 S2
```

then on S1, in a new terminal window, I ran

```
tsocks wget google.com
```

and got the "unable to resolve host address" error.

If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it!! (P.S I am running CentOS on both machines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is not with tsocks - but with DNS server

see the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/tsocks : tsocks will normally not be able to send DNS queries through a SOCKS server since SOCKS V4 works on TCP and DNS normally uses UDP. Version 1.5 and up do however provide a method to force DNS lookups to use TCP, which then makes them proxyable. This option can only enabled at compile time, please consult the INSTALL file for more information.